# Ordenar array multidimensional

Tags: php, array

Dispongo de dos DDBB de dos tipos diferentes (DB2 y SQL Server), para conseguir la información de los dos sition, ejecuto dos consultas diferentes y voy añadiendo los resultados a un array de la siguiente forma:

```
array_push($resultado, $row);
```

De esta forma tengo los datos en el array $resultado , pero no los tengo ordenados, dentro de cada $row hay un campo llamado FECHA_ORDEN que me dejaria el array ordenado de la forma correcta, como podría ordenar para que quedaran los resultados de forma ordenada, he probado con:

```
usort($resultado, "FECHA_ORDEN");
```

Y me devuelve el error:

usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback...

Pongo un ejemplo, una vez realizadas las dos consultas tengo el array de la siguiente forma:

```
TIPO     | FECHA_ORDEN
-------------------------
LINEA    | 20181030111600
CABECERA | 20181030111600 
LINEA    | 20181030101400 
CABECERA | 20181030101400
```

Y me gustaría tenerlo así después de ordenar:

```
TIPO     | FECHA_ORDEN
-------------------------
CABECERA | 20181030101400 
LINEA    | 20181030101400 
CABECERA | 20181030111600 
LINEA    | 20181030111600
```

Comment: Creo que lo mejor es utilizar la función **Order by** de SQL, si quisieras seguir utilizando la función usort, como te respondió @JDev, necesitas defenir una función que pueda comparar el arreglo.

Comment: no puedo usar order by ya que los datos provienen de dos fuentes diferentes y al obtenerlos no vienen ordenados

Comment: ok. Ya entendí. Los quieres ordenar antes de mostrarlos en la vista. Muéstranos por favor la estructura de tu variable **$resultado** y dinos por qué campos los quieres ordenar o cuáles son los criterios o condiciones del orden.

Comment: Los quiero ordenar primero por FECHA_ORDEN que se ordena directamente y de forma correcta y luego por otro campo que es TIPO, solo existe dos tipos CABECERA o LINEA, primero las cabeceras y luego las lineas

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega **todos los detalles** que te mencioné .... Agrega tu código PHP y la estructura de las tablas o rows que estás recibiendo. También detalla los tipos de datos y el formato del date FECHA_ORDEN. Qué es cabecera o linea? No entiendo.

Comment: Ya he añadido mas o menos una descripción

Answer (score 5):

Estas usando mal `usort`. El segundo parametro debe ser el nombre de la función de comparación.

Ejemplo

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");
```

[Fuente](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php)

Comment: Y si quiero hacer una ordenación por dos campos? es decir como order by en SQL

Comment: `$a` y `$b` pueden ser arrays, estructuras u objetos. Dentro puedes hacer las comprobaciones que quieras.

Answer (score 3):

Según tu pregunta, tienes una tabla similar a esta:

```
TIPO     | FECHA_ORDEN
-------------------------
LINEA    | 20181030111600
CABECERA | 20181030111600 
LINEA    | 20181030101400 
CABECERA | 20181030101400
```

Suponiendo que tuvieras un arreglo $resultado en el que las posiciones 0,1,2,..,n son el número de fila y en la segunda posición tienes (TIPO | FECHA_ORDEN):

```
$resultado[0]["TIPO"]="LINEA";
$resultado[0]["FECHA_ORDEN"]="20181030111600";
$resultado[1]["TIPO"]="CABECERA";
$resultado[1]["FECHA_ORDEN"]="20181030111600";
```

Entonces,según tu pregunta quieres ordenar primero por fechas, pero sí las fechas son iguales entonces elegir un segundo criterio de ordenamiento que será el tipo:

```
<?php
function comparador($a, $b)
{
    if (strcmp($a["FECHA_ORDEN"], $b["FECHA_ORDEN"]) == 0) {
        return strcmp($a["TIPO"], $b["TIPO"]);
    }
    return strcmp($a["FECHA_ORDEN"], $b["FECHA_ORDEN"]);
}

usort($resultado,"comparador");
```

Con el código que vemos arriba, podemos hacer un sort, primero por fechas, pero en caso de que las fechas sean idénticas podemos resolverlo con un "sort" por tipo.